# pip exists in python but not found in bash

Tags: pip

My python is 2.7.10

```
python get-pip.py
```

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
```

But when I call pip. It still failed.

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

My `.bash_profile`:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Comment: You can use `python -m pip` instead

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's OK, but how could this happen? Is there something ambiguous in PATH to find the pip?

Comment: From a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022646/python-pip-install-path-what-is-the-correct-location-for-this-and-other-addons): `/usr/local/bin/pip` seems to be the directory to which Pip is installed. Is that on your path? Basically, you just need to figure out where Pip placed itself and add that to your path.

Comment: Oh, yeah, thank you! I have solved this problem after I add the right path in bash_profile.